# How to get data from MDCard by search bar and put it to another MDCard which one is in different MDScreen

Tags: kivy, kivymd, python-3.10

I have many MDCards in .kv file, more than 100 and I tried to write function to find that MDCard what I'm looking for by search bar. But it doesn't work. I feel that I have not enough knowledge.
Help me please to write function!?

Here is my .kv file

```
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<AllGimsScreen>

    MDBoxLayout:
        md_bg_color: (44/255, 44/255, 44/255, 1)

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "root_page"

                MDBoxLayout:
                    id: box_layout
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                    MDRelativeLayout:
                        id: relative_layout
                        size_hint_y: .30

                        MDTextField:
                            id: search_field
                            hint_text: "Search gim"
                            mode: "rectangle"
                            width: "350"
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
                            size_hint_x: None
                        MDIconButton:
                            icon: "magnify"
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .4}
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: (217/255, 208/255, 208/255, 1)
                            on_release: root.searching(search_field.text)

                    MDScrollView:
                        id: searched_view
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        do_scroll_x: False

                        MDList:
                            id: searched_list
                            cols: 3
                            rows: 41
                            spacing: "18dp"
                            padding: "24dp"

                            MD3Card:
                                source: "assets/images/1 gim.png"
                                text: "1 gim"

                            MD3Card:
                                source: "assets/images/2 gim.png"
                                text: "2 gim"

                            MD3Card:
                                source: "assets/images/3 gim.png"
                                text: "3 gim"

                            MD3Card:
                                source: "assets/images/4 gim.png"
                                text: "4 gim"

                            MD3Card:
                                source: "assets/images/5 gim.png"
                                text: "5 gim"

                            MD3Card:
                                source: "assets/images/6 gim.png"
                                text: "6 gim"                            

            MDScreen:
                name: "search_results"

                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "arrow-left"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "root_page"
                        root.clear_results()

                MDLabel:
                    id: search_label
                    text: ""
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
                    halign: "center"
                    font_name: "assets/fonts/01389_ALD721L.ttf"
                    font_size: "20sp"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: (217/255, 208/255, 208/255, 1)

                MDScrollView:
                    do_scroll_y: True
                    do_scroll_x: False
                    size_hint_y: .9

                    MDList:
                        id: search_list
                        cols: 3
                        rows: 41
                        spacing: "18dp"
                        padding: "24dp"
```

Here is AllGimScreen class

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

from Screens.AllGimsScreen.components.card import MD3Card


class AllGimsScreen(MDScreen):

    def searching(self, search_field):
        if search_field != "":
            self.ids.search_label.text = search_field
            self.ids.screen_manager.current = "search_results"
            self.ids.search_list = f"{self.ids.searched_list.source}"
            self.ids.search_list = f"{self.ids.searched_list.text}"

    def clear_results(self):
        self.ids.search_field.text = ""
```

I tried this function but it's not working

```
class AllGimsScreen(MDScreen):

    def searching(self, search_field):
        if search_field != "":
            self.ids.search_label.text = search_field
            self.ids.screen_manager.current = "search_results"
            self.ids.search_list = f"{self.ids.searched_list.source}"
            self.ids.search_list = f"{self.ids.searched_list.text}"

    def clear_results(self):
        self.ids.search_field.text = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is solution. That was very simple!:

```
def searching(self, search_field):
    if search_field != "":
        self.ids.search_label.text = search_field
        self.ids.screen_manager.current = "search_results"
        for key, val in self.ids.items():
            if search_field.lower() in key:
                card = MD3Card(
                    source=val.source,
                    text=val.text,
                )
                self.ids.search_list.add_widget(card)
            elif search_field.upper() in key:
                card = MD3Card(
                    source=val.source,
                    text=val.text,
                )
                self.ids.search_list.add_widget(card)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).